# Prove: If $n \ge 0$, then $S^n$ is not a retract of $D^{n+1}$ using homology functors.

Tags: category-theory, functors, retraction

> Prove: If $n \ge 0$, then $S^n$ is not a retract of $D^{n+1}$ using
>   homology functors.

The book I'm reading says: For each $n \ge 0$, there is a homology functor $H_n$ with the following properties: for each topological space $X$ there is an abelian group $H_n(X)$, and for each continuous function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ there is a homomorphism $H_n(f):H_n(X) \rightarrow H_n(Y)$, such that

> $H_n(g \circ f) = H_n(X) \circ H_n(Y)$
>
> $H_n(S^n)\neq 0, n \ge 0$
>
> $H_n(D^{n+1})=0, n \ge 0$
>
> $H_n(1_X)$ is the identity function on $H_n(X)$

**This is the only thing said so far about what a homology functor is, the book has developed no theory besides what it in the above box.**

The book begins the proof by assuming there's a retraction, converting the commutative $1 = r \circ i$ ($i$ is the inclusion mapping) graph to homology functors, and then states that since $H_n(D^{n+1})=0$, then $H_n(1)=0$.  But $H_n(1)$ is the identity on $H_n(S^n)$, which contradicts the identity relationship because $H_n(S^n) \neq 0.$

What I don't understand is how does it follow that $H_n(1)=0$ and $H_n(D^{n+1})=0$?  What does it mean that a homomorphism is $0$, $H_n(f)=0$, and what does it mean for an abelian group to be $0$, $H_n(D^{n+1})=0$?  Is this both identity notation for group and homomorphisms, respectively?

Comment: You should give a precise reference to the book you are reading (including the exact quote/ wording, too). *Or* give precise quotes.
For once, the 'for each space, there is a Homology functor' sounds very wrong already and it appears you are mixing things up.    
You are also using the plural of the word 'homology functor' which sounds like you are confused about the whole matter... what one usually talks about is a 'homology theory', which, for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ gives a functor $H_n$ from the category of pairs of topological spaces into the category of Abelian groups.

Comment: Edited to include exactly what is in the book.

Comment: An Abelian group $G$ is $0$, if $G = \{0\}$, that is, if it consists only of its neutral element. A homomorphism is $0$, if it sends everything to $0$. This is consistent in the sense that for groups $G,\, G'$, one can build the group of homomorphisms from $G$ to $G'$, where addition comes from pointwise addition, i.e. $f + g$ for two such homomorphisms is defined by $(f + g)(x)=f(x) + g(x)$; then, the homomorphism that is constantly $0$ is the neutral element of addition on the group of homomorphisms $G \longrightarrow G'$.

Comment: @polynomial_donut So since $H_n(D^{n+1})={0}$, $H_n(i) = 0: H_n(S^n) \rightarrow$ $\{ \text{neutral element of $H_n(D^{n+1})$}\}$, and therefore $H_n(r) \circ 0$ maps the neutral element of $H_n(D^{n+1})$ to the neutral element of $H_n(S^n)$.  But since it's commutative and $H_n(1)$ is the identity mapping, this is a contradiction?

Comment: You should first study some basic algebra... the neutral element (one usually writes $0$ for the neutral element in any Abelian group) is *always* sent to $0$ by group homomorphisms. This is no contradiction. It all boils down to correctly combining the following facts Ben West has already stated (I think his answer is a bit cumbersome, although it looks correct):
  1. By definition, a functor sends identity maps to identity maps.
  2. A group-hom. with domain or codomain $0$ is the $0$-morphism, especially, $id_G=0\iff G=0$
  3. If $f$ is a group homomorphism and $f=g \circ 0$, then $f=0$

Comment: P.s.: If comments are helpful, please upvote (but don't accidentally click the spam flag ;) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So suppose you have maps $i\colon S^n\to D^{n+1}$ and $r\colon D^{n+1}\to S^n$ such that $r\circ i=1\colon S^n\to S^n$. Since $H_n$ is a (covariant) functor it preserves composition of arrows, so you have $H_n(1)=H_n(r)\circ H_n(i)$.

We have $H_n(i)\colon H_n(S^n)\to H_n(D^{n+1})$, a morphism of groups. But $H_n(D^{n+1})=0$, (the zero group), so necessarily $H_n(i)=0$, (the zero map), since the only possible image is $0$. Then $H_n(r)\circ H_n(i)=H_n(r)\circ 0=0$, the zero here being the $0$ map. The reason for this is because any group morphism composed with the $0$ morphism is the zero morphism, because $H_n(r)$ always sends the element $0$ to the element $0$, as a morphism of abelian groups.

So
$$
H_n(1)=H_n(r)\circ H_n(i)=H_n(r)\circ 0=0\quad (\text{the zero map}).
$$

But this is a contradiction, since functors preserve identity arrows, so $H_n(1)\colon H_n(S^n)\to H_n(S^n)$ must be the identity map on these groups, so it must be nonzero since $H_n(S^n)\neq 0$, that is, $H_n(S^n)$ is not the zero group.